Connectedness of a subspace of $M_2(\mathbb C)$
Let $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ be the space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries from complex field $\mathbb{C}$. Is the set $\left\{A=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix} \in M_2(\mathbb{C}) : \|A\| <1 \ \& \ a_{11} \ne 0  \right\}$ connected? (Here, $\|A\|$ is the square root of maximum eigenvalue of $A^*A$).
What I know:

I know that the space $\{A \in M_2(\mathbb{C}) : \|A\| <1 \}$ is connected, in fact convex, because $\|tA+(1-t)B\| \leq t\|A\| +(1-t)\|B\|< t+(1-t)=1$ for any $A, B$ with $\|A\|, \|B\| <1$ and $0<t<1$.

Any two norms on finite dimension space are equivalent and so, one can take any norm, because the spaces will be homeomorphic. Under homeomorpshism, connectedness is preserved.



Removing a proper complex subvariety from a connected open subset of ${\mathbb C}^n$ preserves connectivity. It is easier if the subvariety is linear as in your case.

@MoisheKohan Is there any simpler proof of the fact that the set mentioned in the question is connected?

Of course: Consider the complex affine line through two points of your convex set and remove from it the intersection with the complex linear subspace $a_{11}=0$, which is at most one point. Now you should be able to finish the proof.

Your space is homeomorphic to $\Bbb C^*\times\Bbb C^3$. A product of connected spaces is connected.
